# Some edges are not smoothing in Blender

Tags: normals, edges

I imported this geometry from Zbrush. As you can see the other edges around this area were smooth-able, but I could not get the edges connected to this cone shaped ridge to smooth. The first image is a screen grab of the geometry edges. The second image shows what the geometry looks like. I tried everything that normally works to get them to smooth. Clear Sharp. Shading Smooth. Recalculate Normals. But they are not smoothing. What could cause this?
[image]

[image]

Comment: What exactly is happening with those vertices in that ridge? It looks like there are more there than needed, it might help to be dealing with only a single row of vertices there. Would adding a [subsurf modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/subsurf.html) work in your situation? A couple of edge loops in that area may also help. And have you tried adding an edge split modifier and adjusting the angle setting?

Answer (score 2):

In the end I retopologised the model and it was much cleaner. It was for the best because the result had half the number of polygons. Thanks for the input.

To add more information the topology now looks like this. While it doesn't flow like it used to, it smooths nicely and that is what's important for this.

[image]

[image]